# Air for iOS: included files directory path

Tags: ios, flash, actionscript-3, air

Due to decisions out of my control I've created a iPad app by way of a CS5.5 Flash build and using the 'Air for iOS' publish.

In the 'Air for iOS' settings I've included a file.

The issue I'm having is in trying to call the file and not knowing what the path is.

I'm hoping this is a case where files added in this manner are placed in a consistent location.

Is that the case? And if so, what would the path be?

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All application files are placed in the "application" directory. You can access files in this directory using the app: URI scheme, as in: app://file.ext or app://assets/picture.jpg, etc.

You can also use File.applicationDirectory to get a file reference:

var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("file.ext");